# setting form authentication in impersonate

Tags: sql, asp.net, windows-authentication, impersonation

I have an intranet website. My database uses windows authentication. My website uses the network credential by using `logonuser()`.

```
IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;

        bool result = LogonUser(txtUsername.Text, txtDomain.Text, txtPassword.Text, 2, 0, ref token); //2, 0, ref token);
        if (result)
        {
            WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(token);
            WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtDomain.Text + "\\" + txtUsername.Text, false);
            using (SqlConnection cnn=new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand("select * from [user] where username=@user", cnn))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",txtDomain.Text+"\\"+txtUsername.Text);

                    cnn.Open();
                    SqlDataReader rdr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    rdr.Read();
                    if(rdr.HasRows)
                    {   
                        cnn.Close();
                        lblNotification.Text = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
                        Session.Add("principal", new WindowsPrincipal(newId));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        lblNotification.Text="Username or Password is Invalid";
                    }
                }
            }
```

The code executes properly including the sql but when it goes to the next page (home.aspx) I get this error:

[image: error message]

The error is encountered in the windows authentication in sql. 'ECP' is my domain and 'PHAPPCVTL002198$' is my computer name but I was not expecting that. I was expecting the username that I entered in the login form.